# Count first vote from email if user votes multiple times

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So we use a Microsoft Form that links all data to an excel file where we get all votes from the form.

The problem I'm having is that I need to be able to count the number of votes for each song on this current day. If there is are multiple votes from a user only the first vote should be counted.

How should I do this?

I've tried this:

```
=ANTAL.OMF(Table1[Jeg stemmer på];E3;Table1[Starttid];">="&IDAG();Table1[Finde Duplicate];1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an error after removing some old entries.
In my find duplicate column it should have been:

```
=ANTAL.OMF($J$16:$J16;[@Email])
```

but there was

```
 =ANTAL.OMF($J$16:$J1106;[@Email])
```